# Pattern não permite caractere acentuado?

Tags: html

Tenho um formulário e estou validando da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" name="assunto" tabindex="5" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9. - , ]{5,}" required>
```

Só que se digito algum caractere acentuado (á, à, ã, ç) ele não valida, tem alguma pattern específico que permite digitar esse tipo de caractere?

Comment: muda o encooding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem dois erros e um problema na Expressão Regular do atributo *pattern* que você definiu.

1. Eu não consegui fazer um barra-letra equivalente à classe POSIX `[[:alnum:]_]` funcionar, então o que você tem para caracteres não numéricos hoje não considera acentos. Ampliar a lista resolve:

   ```
   [A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9]
   ```
2. O hífen é um caractere special dentro de uma lista. Ou você o escapa ou o adiciona no final da lista:

   ```
   [A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9-]
   ```
3. Corrigindo os dois primeiros esse se torna opcional, mas espaços em branco não precisam aparecer mais de uma vez:

   ```
   [A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9., -]{5,}
   ```

Exemplo [no JSBin](http://jsbin.com/togomesotu/1/)

Comment: perfeito, valeu!